# Reusing cloudformation template for AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I have AWS SAM template, part of which looks like this:

```
  # .......
  InternalApiKey:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
    Properties:
      Enabled: true
      Name: !Sub internal_api_key_${Env}
      Value: !Ref InternalApiKeyValue
      StageKeys:
        - RestApiId: !Ref ServerlessRestApi
          StageName: Prod
  InternalUsagePlan:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan
    Properties:
      ApiStages:
        - ApiId: !Ref ServerlessRestApi
          Stage: Prod
  InternalUsagePlanKey:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey
    Properties:
      KeyId: !Ref InternalApiKey
      KeyType: API_KEY
      UsagePlanId: !Ref InternalUsagePlan
  #......
```

Deploying this template as two distinct application (CloudFormation stack) with `sam deploy --stack-name=stack-a` and `sam deploy --stack-name=stack-b` fails with the following error even when api key names are different:

> API Key already exists (Service:                                                                                                                                        AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 409; Error                                                                                                                                                  Code: ConflictException; Request ID:
> redacted; Proxy:
> null)

How can I deploy two stacks from this template?

Comment: A different key value and your problem will go away. So if you are setting the api key value yourself ensure they are unique. Not sure why that's a constraint between different stages.

Comment: @AbdulMoeez That is the reason! I'll accept this once you submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different key value and your problem will go away. So if you are setting the api key value yourself ensure they are unique. Not sure why that's a constraint between different stages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to provide a value for your key? It's an optional parameter. You can remove it from your template and AWS will generate a unique key for you in each deployment.